# Is it not correct to mount GCS on its own WAS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am doing video services and uploading videos to Google Cloud Storage.

You saw that it was not correct to mount GCS on its own WAS(web Service).

My Question

1. Is it wrong to mount its own WAS and GCS?

   (Do you recommend to mount your own WAS and GCS?)
2. How do I mount my own WAS and GCS?
3. If not, how should I use GCS?
4. Are there related documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve videos that are stored in GCS, a common approach would be to use URL links to publicly accessible buckets and objects in them. You can have a look at an article about accessing public data [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data). Before that you would need to [make your data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

You can mount GCS buckets as file systems on your own Linux system with the help of the open source Cloud Storage FUSE adapter. You can check out the GCP documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) and if you wish to learn more about GCS FUSE you can check out the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/) where it is also explained how to install and mount it.

If your wish to upload and download Cloud Storage objects using standard file system semantics in your application, Cloud Storage FUSE is a suitable choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have a question. Can I use GCSFUSE to connect the server and GCS instead of the file system? Do you recommend connecting the server to the GCS?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean by "connect the server and GCS instead of the file system". What do you want to do and why do you want to mount GCS and not just use the URL links for accessing public data? To answer your updated question, I would not recommend to use it if you are developing an app on Google App Engine for serving videos.

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me ask you a question again.
The server I am talking about is the web service.(I mean WAS. ex. java, php..)
Can WAS and GCS be mount?

Comment: GSC FUSE can be successfully installed on Linux and Mac OS X. I am not aware of the architecture of the WAS or the operating system running, you will probably have to investigate this on your own.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I learned from the link that told me how to mount GCS Fuse.  GCS fuses only provide Linux 64-bit setup.  Do you know if Linux 32bit is available?  I'm using 32-bit on a Linux (CentOS6) environment

Comment: @KMi the best way to find this out would be to post the question on the GitHub page because I am not aware of this.